# Object is not imported properly in a Flask structure

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to learn Flask from *Instant Flask Web Development* book following it step-by-step but I get the error presented below.
(It seems to be a problem with circular imports.)
The questions are:

*Can someone explain what would be the fix and detail the circular imports?*

**Directory structure:**

```
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── sched
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── app.py
    ├── app.pyc
    ├── static
    └── templates
```

**manager.py:**

```
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from sched import app

manager = Manager(app)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**`__init__.py`** is ampty.

**Command line generated error:**

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Comment: I have proposed a slightly different architecture but i think it's clearer and i have separated the views in my answer below. There is no single solution but mine is working ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
from sched import app
```

you are importing the `app` module. The `app` object is inside the module. The import you want to use is

```
from sched.app import app
```

Comment: @dim:I missed `.app` in `from sched.app import app` .

Answer (score 1):

Alternative architecture :

```python
# app.py:

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

from flask.ext.script import Manager
manager = Manager(app)

# __init__.py:

from .sched import app, manager
import sched.views # for your views
import sched.commands # for additional commands


# manager.py:

from sched import manager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()

 #views.py:

from .app import app

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but still get and error: `$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sched import manager
  File "/Users/joe/Programming/Python/Flask_tutorial/sched/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .sched import app, manager
ImportError: No module named sched
`

Comment: are you on python3 ? Otherwise keep your architecture and you have the answer by dim for your first proposal

Comment: No. I use Python2.7.9. Yes, dim's answer seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: fine ! (you can adapt my code for python2.7 but it's made for python3 )

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following [an app factory pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/) for your app.

```
manage.py
sched/
  __init__.py
```

in `__init__.py` you can do the following:

```
from flask import Flask
def create_app():
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config['DEBUG'] = True
  return app
```

in `manage.py`

```
from app import create_app
from flask.ext.script import Manager
app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  manager.run()
```

This tends to be an extensible solution for larger application structures.